# Storing actions in a stack for 'undo' purpose

Tags: python, class

Because stack allows to either push or pop, it is suitable to redo actions by just simply popping the latest action by the user. I have a stack class where:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,item,the_next = None):
        self.item = item
        self.next = the_next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)

class LinkedStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
        self.count = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    def isFull(self):
        return False

    def reset(self):
        self.top = None
        self.count = 0

    def __str__(self):
        current = self.top
        ans = ""
        while not (current is None):
            ans += str(current)
            ans += '\n'
            current = current.next
        return ans

    def _get_node(self,index):
        if 0<= index< len(self):
            current = self.top
            while index>0:
               current = current.next
               index -=1
            return current

    def pop(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise StopIteration("Stack is empty")
        output = self.top.item
        self.top = self.top.next
        self.count -=1
        return output

    def push(self,item):
        newNode = Node(item)
        newNode.next = self.top
        self.top = newNode
        self.count +=1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = LinkedStack()
```

and in another file, i import the stack from above and try to implement the undo action.

```
from Stack import LinkedStack
class Editor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self._list = LinkedList()
        self._stack = LinkedStack()

def command(self,userCommand):
    userCommand = userCommand.split(' ')
    try:
        if userCommand[0] == 'insert':
            position = int(userCommand[1])
            if len(userCommand) ==1:
                raise Exception('no num is given')
            textInput = input("Enter your text:")
            self._stack.push(self.insertText(position,textInput)) #I'm thinking of adding the action into the stack by pushing it.
            print(self._list)
            pass
    except Exception:
        print('?')

    if userCommand[0] == 'undo':   #here if they choose to undo, by right i just pop the last action from the stack
        self._stack.pop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myCommand = Editor()
    while True:
        command = input('Enter an option:')
        if command.lower() == 'quit':
           break
        else:
            myCommand.command(command)
```

because I'm merely undoing actions, i thought of adding the command actions into a stack. if you take a look at the insert command above, where i added a comment, am i doing it correctly? Because I'm running out of ideas.

By the way, the insertText is a function which is working and I'm not planning to paste it here as it's getting lengthy. LinkedList() is just a linked list class i imported from another file as well.

The 'undo' doesn't seemed to revert the state. For example, if my LinkedList() contains:

```
1
2
3
4
None
```

and if i use the insert function to insert another number, 7 at index 1

```
1
7
2
3
4
None
```

and if i undo the action, I'm supposed to have:

```
1
2
3
4
None
```

Comment: Look up the `memento pattern` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Comment: If your latest action is "undo", will another "undo" undo the undo?

Comment: @COLDSPEED no by right, it only undo the other functions aside from itself.

Comment: undo/redo is better modeled as a tree with only parent pointers.

Comment: Unlike that `memento pattern` link, you should generally not store the whole state. But it should be pretty simple, a class represting: "starting position X, delete characters `'abc'` and insert characters `'def'`" - which and represent pure inserts/deletes as well as atomic replacements, and can be applied in both directions.

Comment: If you want to undo/redo a more complex operation such as "replace all by regex", simply represent that as an opaque combination of multiple simple undo operations.

Comment: Talking patterns, are you describing the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), @o11c ?

Comment: @spectras Apparently it counts as that. Though most of that article is rather misleading from the undo/redo point of view. (I'm not big into naming patterns when it's clearer without one)

Comment: I thought so. Yes, the idea is for every command (operation) to carry a way to apply it both forwards and backwards. As long as destructive commands remember what they destroyed, they can be reversed. *(I'm not either, but knowing the name is useful to establish a common language for talking about code concepts with other devs - here I thought the name might ring a bell if OP had heard about it before)*